# How to fix expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions

Tags: python, debugging, keras, neural-network

I got an error:"Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 256, 455, 3)" . The input data is 40,000 RGB images(256pixels x 455 pixels) that have three channels. In each batch, there are 32 images. The outputs are angles of the steering wheel, so they are not categories. How can I fix this error?

```
enter code here
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=data, 
class_mode = 
"input",directory="../input/driving_dataset/driving_dataset/", 
x_col="files", y_col="results", batch_size=32,color_mode = 
'rgb',target_size = (256,455),subset = 'training')

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=data, 
class_mode = 
"input",directory="../input/driving_dataset/driving_dataset/", 
x_col="files", y_col="results", batch_size=32,color_mode = 
'rgb',target_size = (256,455),subset = 'validation')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24,(5,5),padding ="valid",input_shape = (256,455,3), 
activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(36,(5,5),padding = "valid", activation = "relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(48,(5,5),padding = "valid", activation = "relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1164, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = "relu")
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss="mse")

model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // 32,
validation_data = validation_generator, 
validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 32,
epochs = 2)
```

Comment: Start by telling us where the error occurs.  Next review how this model works.  Does it talk about using 2 or 3d images?  Often when models expect 2 dimensions, one dimension represents samples, and the other features.  You may have 32 samples, but how many 'features' are you modeling?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `class_mode="input"`, which means the generator will take the input images as labels as well. You should set `class_mode="other"` so the values in the `y_col` will be used as the labels.